# How to avoid memory leaks in viewpager

Tags: android

I have viewpager with several fragments.I have list of thumbnails in viewpager.Sometimes i am getting MemoryOutofError.How to avoid memory leaks in viewpager?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/13604270/3871352

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ViewPager with images: memory leak/app crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586963/android-viewpager-with-images-memory-leak-app-crashes)