# Sliding 4 images using view pager is very slow

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-viewpager

I am trying to create intro tour for the app with 4 image using viewpager.
Its taking very much time to slide from previous to next image.

I am getting following log in logcat while sliding

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I tried following methods:

1 setImageResource() does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using 2.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or 3.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.
Size and resolution of your images can also be a cause of slow scrolling, 
try creating thumbnails images of your large images and use.(I reduce images size from 100kb to 30-50kb in drawable)

Also tried stack overflow answers below:

[Memory leak with images in viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586963/android-viewpager-with-images-memory-leak-app-crashes)

Still images taking much time from previous to next images in view pager .
I tested it on different device. On moto x play its slowest and other devices like samsung, moto E, Lenovo are little faster but still not upto mark.

I have 4 images in drawable folder and using code below I am trying to slide the images.

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_pager_item);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(mResources[position]);
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try to change setImageDrawable to setImageResource. It is working for me.

Comment: tried that as well , still same output !

Comment: 1) First check the size of your images and resolutions . 2) Set _largeHeap="true"_ in manifest file. 3) Use _Glide_ to load your images.

Comment: Size of the images are 34kb, 30kb, 50kb, 40kb. I am onto it.  Thanks for quick response !

Comment: post your full activity code

Comment: r u sure setImageResource() causes the pblm

Comment: Yes!        Same problem!

Comment: Using glide still same on moto x play . No difference between setImageResource() or Glide.with()....  . Its working fine using any method in device like lenovo, samsung, moto e low end devices but moto x play having problem

Comment: Is it because moto x play are high end device and I only have 4 image in drawable folder but not in any one of drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: @Piyush thanks  2) Set largeHeap="true" in manifest file. 3) Use Glide to load your images. Helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Putting your Images in particular Drawable folder to View in different densities! so you don't have any rendering problems

By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps, shrink or enlarge. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, praneeth. This is excellent answer. I have 5 pages in my viewpager. And each page has one recyclerview with some big photos. The viewpager was slow, the recyclerview was slow and the drawerLayout had a lag when opening. With this answer, three problems have solved.

Comment: @Arash Glad to know that!

Answer (score 3):

I just solved it by putting all the 4 image in drawable to different folder xhdpi, xxhdpi, mdpi, xxxhdpi as well.

I found out that moto x play is xxhpi but there were no image in xxhdpi thats why it was not working.

Now you can swipe with any speed may be with the speed of The FLASH  :D

Answer (score 1):

Please use Glide for ViewPager's image loading. It will improve ViewPager pagination performance, solve OutOfMemoryError, etc.

Example:

```
    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_about_us))
                    .into(imageView);
```